# Making a procedural terrain with Transvoxel/Marching cubes and 3D perlin noise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain, perlin-noise, marching-cubes

I'm working on an implementation of Transvoxel and it works fine, but I can't get on with the noise. Now I'm generating a 2d heightmap using perlin noise and using the heightmap I'm setting the cell values, but I don't have any idea on how to generate the values for the cells. Actually they have to be between -127 and 128, and they have to increase and decrease smoothly, but I can't generate those values.

EDIT:

I stopped using 3d noise and I'm trying to do something with 2d noise. Now, I can triangulate a density field as I'm using marching cubes and transvoxel since about half a year. But the only thing I don't know is that if I generate a 2d heightmap to have terrain features like mountains then I don't know what densities do I have to use. I tried just simply give everything solid -127 and everything non-solid 127 and I also tried getting a heightmap value at a given (x,z) and then just adding y to it like: (x, 0, z) = 42, (x, 1, z) = 43, (x, 2, z) = 44 etc...
But theese variations generate blocky terrains like the image below:

[image]

What should I do to make it smooth? Vertex locations are floats with non-whole values so it shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Transvoxel is a more complex implementation of Marching Cubes and I suggest you forget Transvoxel for now, study Marching Cubes first.

In summary, Marching cubes receives noise from 0 to 1, where 0 is no terrain and 1 is terrain. You just need to write 1 where you are planning to have terrain. For instance, generate a small map with 1 value where y < 3, on all X and Z positions of your map. You should get a flat terrain.

Try out! =)

Comment: Well actually I understand how marching cubes and transvoxel is working. I can triangulate a world, but the only thing I don't know is to use noise and density TOGETHER. LIke I generate a heightmap using 2d perlin noise, but I don't really know what values should I use as densities. If I simply use -127 for solid and 127 for non-solid then I get a blocky terrain. But I don't know what values do I have to use to make it smooth.

Comment: @Statey On marching cubes implementation I was working, I used 0 for non-solid and 1 for solid. Any value between 0 or 1 will show how far the triangle will be draw from original point position. Or to determine height. But i think you need a shader solution, to make it smoother like this https://forum.unity3d.com/attachments/biomadeserto-jpg.85115/

Comment: Now I've implemented transvoxel algorithm I don't know that you know something about it, but it uses signed bytes as density values (in the range of -127 and 128). It can generate beautiful terrains on it's own (I mean without any special normals or shaders). My only problem is that when I use a height map with bigger frequency it generates a smooth terrain, but of course it's spiky. If I use a height map with lower frequency it generates a realistic terrain shape, but it's kinda blocky.

Comment: You need to mix some height maps to achieve this. One with bigger frequency and one with lower frequency. This is how is done on voxel games.